# How to get value from global variable in another module python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have file say `test1.py` and it has variable `var1 = ''` and in one of the methods in `test1.py` I'm updating value of `var1` as

```
global var1 
var1 = 'new_value'
```

And I can see value updated by printing it from another method in `test1.py`.
Now I have another file `test2.py` In which I'm calling var1 as `var_new = test1.var1`
But when I print it I still get ''.
I think at the start of suite it's initializing all modules. But when I am calling method in test2.py it is getting value when it initialized? How can I get updated value?
So `var_new` prints `''`

If I use `get_var()` method then I get updated value. So I guess I have create the method always?

Comment: in test2.py try `test1.var1="new_value" `

Comment: are you saying assign new value from test2.py? If that's the case I can re-assign, but can't I use the value which I have already assigned or updated?

Comment: post your test1.py and test2.py so we can see..(I hope they are not lengthy)

Comment: well, going by your description it work fine to me, maybe the problem is where you modify var1?? you do it in a function in test1? better show us the code to see the problem

Comment: I edited, so is var_new suppose to have value '' or 'new_value'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally understand the problem, by your description you have something like this

test1.py

```
var1=""

def foo():
    global var1
    var1="new_valor"

def bar():
    print(var1)
```

test2.py

```
import test1
var_new=test1.var1
print(var_new)
```

if that is the case, yes you get a empty string because you don't call `foo` to modify var1, so you have to call it first or modify from test2 because `foo` is not called at load time so var1 stay with the value it was first assigned.

Comment: yes! thanks that's the right question. so even though if I call foo() before calling test2 it will print var1 as ''. I guess I have to use get method then. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By doing this:

```
var1 = test1.var1
```

you copy the content of the test1.var1 string into var1. But if later test1.var1 is modified, var1 is not.

```
>>> var1="test"
>>> var2=var1
>>> var2+= "a"
>>> var2
'testa'
>>> var1
'test'
```

So if you want to get the value of test1.var1, you should always access it threw `test1.var1`.

Comment: yes that's how I'm accessing but it prints '', I was hoping it will print 'new_value' since I modified it, won't it?

Comment: I should... I made the following test:
test1.py

`
     global var1
     var1='test'
`

test2.py 
`
    import test1
    print test1.var1
`

$python test2.py 
test

Comment: before global var1, did you assign it as var1=''?

Comment: No, I assign it as 'test' after global var1. Then on test2 I get the correct value.

Comment: When I try to assign var1 before global, i get a warning "SyntaxWarning: name 'var1' is assigned to before global declaration", but it still works.